# openshift origin ansible to install docker-engine rather than docker?

Tags: openshift-origin

Is it possible that openshift origin 1.4 ansible to install docker-engine (latest version 1.13.0) rather than docker ?

By default, it always try to install docker not docker-engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [1.4 release](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/release-1.4) of [OpenShift Ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible) does not support installing Docker 1.13 at the moment. The [documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html) lists the supported Operating Systems and version of Docker, which, for Origin 1.4, is Docker 1.12.

The use of different versions is not supported and not tested.

As per `docker` versus `docker-engine`, there are technical differences in their contents, more information can be found at http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/docker_patches/. OpenShift Origin is tested to work with the `docker` package from Project Atomic.